# Netty 4.0.19.Final Bootstrap.connect CPU usage issues

Tags: netty

I'm having issues with `Bootstrap.connect` taking up a lot of CPU power from my application. I am currently using a 64-thread threadpool (mainly for blocking DNS resolution) to dispatch 300 connection attempts every 10 seconds to Netty. The purpose of this program is to query Minecraft servers listed on my website, Minestatus.

CPU usage spikes to 100% every time these connections are dispatched. I've attached a screenshot of a JMX connection sampling CPU usage. Any idea what's going on?[image: CPU usage sampling]

Here is what my dispatch code looks like:

```
private void dispatch(EventLoopGroup workerGroup, final MinecraftServer server) {
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    bootstrap.group(workerGroup).channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
    bootstrap.handler(new UpdaterPipelineInitializer(timeout));
    bootstrap.attr(MinecraftServer.SERVER_KEY, server);
    bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, timeout);

    bootstrap.connect(server.getAddress(), server.getPort()).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            server.incrementAttemptedConnections();
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                server.incrementSuccessfulConnections();
                server.setOnline(true);
            } else {
                future.cause().printStackTrace();
                server.setOnline(false);
                MinestatusUpdater.getDatabaseHandler().saveServer(server);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please share the snapshot